# Ошибка при написании кода на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Пишу простенький калькулятор на *Python* с помощью *PyQt5*. Но при запуске программы вылетает ошибка:

> `'Main' object has no attribute 'numbers'`

код:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from sys import argv, exit


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(694, 440)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 160, 321, 231))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_9, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_6, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_7, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_8, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_10, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 160, 81, 231))
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget_2")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_12, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_14.setObjectName("pushButton_14")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_14, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_13.setObjectName("pushButton_13")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_13, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_11, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_15 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_15.setObjectName("pushButton_15")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_15, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.table.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 80, 311, 61))
        self.table.setObjectName("table")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 694, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
        self.pushButton_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "*"))
        self.pushButton_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "/"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.pushButton_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "="))


class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        [i.clicked.connect(self.run) for i in self.numbers.buttons()]
        [i.clicked.connect(self.calc) for i in self.symbols.buttons()]
        self.data = ""

        self.data_eval = ""

    def run(self):
        if self.data != "0":
            self.data = self.data + self.sender().text()
            self.data_eval = self.data_eval + self.sender().text()
            self.lineEdit.display(self.data)
        else:
            self.data = self.sender().text()
            self.data_eval = self.sender().text()
            self.table.display(self.data)
```

Comment: Ну да, а откуда по-вашему numbers должен взяться-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем примере нет объявления переменной `self.numbers` 
и трудно представить, каким образом вы собираетесь составить список Кнопок, глядя на `self.numbers.buttons()`.
Это не очень похоже на связывание события кнопки с сигналом `clicked`.

Глядя на `class Ui_MainWindow`, который получен из Qt Designerа,
вам надо буде привязать каждую кнопку к нужному слоту, как-то так:

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run)
```

и затем уже в слоте анализировать что вы нажали и что с ним делать.

Виджет QLCDNumber, по-моему тоже не очень подойдет вам.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
#from sys import argv, exit


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(694, 440)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 160, 321, 231))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_9, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_6, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_7, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_8, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_10, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 160, 81, 231))
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget_2")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_12, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_14.setObjectName("pushButton_14")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_14, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_13.setObjectName("pushButton_13")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_13, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_11, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_15 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_15.setObjectName("pushButton_15")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_15, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.table.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 80, 311, 61))
        self.table.setObjectName("table")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 694, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
        self.pushButton_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "*"))
        self.pushButton_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "/"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.pushButton_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "="))


class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

#        [i.clicked.connect(self.run) for i in self.numbers.buttons()]
#        [i.clicked.connect(self.calc) for i in self.symbols.buttons()]
#        self.data = ""
#        self.data_eval = ""

        self.data = ''
        self.pushButton_10.clicked.connect(self.run)    # Button - 0
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run)       # Button - 1
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.run)     # Button - 2
        ...
        self.pushButton_15.clicked.connect(self.run)    # Button - =

    def run(self):
        self.data = self.sender().text()

        self.table.display(str(int(self.table.value())) + self.data)


        """
        if self.data != "0":
            self.data = self.data + self.sender().text()
            self.data_eval = self.data_eval + self.sender().text()
            self.lineEdit.display(self.data)
        else:
            self.data = self.sender().text()
            self.data_eval = self.sender().text()
            self.table.display(self.data)
        """

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Вот вам один из примеров реализации калькулятора на Python с помощью PyQt:**

```
import math
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGridLayout, QLayout, QLineEdit,
                             QSizePolicy,  QToolButton, QWidget)


class Button(QToolButton):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.setText(text)

    def sizeHint(self):
        size = super(Button, self).sizeHint()
        size.setHeight(size.height() + 20)    
        size.setWidth(max(size.width(), size.height()))
        return size


class Calculator(QWidget):
    NumDigitButtons = 10

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Calculator, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pendingAdditiveOperator       = ''  # ожидающий аддитивный оператор
        self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator = ''  # ожидающий мультипликативный оператор

        self.sumInMemory       = 0.0
        self.sumSoFar          = 0.0
        self.factorSoFar       = 0.0
        self.waitingForOperand = True

        self.display = QLineEdit('0')
        self.display.setReadOnly(True)
        self.display.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        self.display.setMaxLength(15)
        font = self.display.font()
        font.setPointSize(font.pointSize() + 8)
        self.display.setFont(font)

        self.digitButtons = []

        for i in range(Calculator.NumDigitButtons):
            self.digitButtons.append(self.createButton(str(i),
                                     self.digitClicked))

        self.pointButton      = self.createButton(".", self.pointClicked)
        self.changeSignButton = self.createButton(u"\N{PLUS-MINUS SIGN}",
                self.changeSignClicked)

        self.backspaceButton = self.createButton("Backspace",
                                                  self.backspaceClicked)
        self.clearButton     = self.createButton("Clear",     self.clear)
        self.clearAllButton  = self.createButton("Clear All", self.clearAll)

        self.clearMemoryButton = self.createButton("MC", self.clearMemory)
        self.readMemoryButton  = self.createButton("MR", self.readMemory)
        self.setMemoryButton   = self.createButton("MS", self.setMemory)
        self.addToMemoryButton = self.createButton("M+", self.addToMemory)

        self.divisionButton = self.createButton(u"\N{DIVISION SIGN}",
                self.multiplicativeOperatorClicked)
        self.timesButton = self.createButton(u"\N{MULTIPLICATION SIGN}",
                self.multiplicativeOperatorClicked)
        self.minusButton = self.createButton("-", self.additiveOperatorClicked)
        self.plusButton  = self.createButton("+", self.additiveOperatorClicked)

        self.squareRootButton = self.createButton("Sqrt",
                self.unaryOperatorClicked)
        self.powerButton = self.createButton(u"x\N{SUPERSCRIPT TWO}",
                self.unaryOperatorClicked)
        self.reciprocalButton = self.createButton("1/x",
                self.unaryOperatorClicked)
        self.equalButton = self.createButton("=", self.equalClicked)

        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetFixedSize)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.display,         0, 0, 1, 6)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.backspaceButton, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.clearButton,     1, 2, 1, 2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.clearAllButton,  1, 4, 1, 2)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.clearMemoryButton, 2, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.readMemoryButton,  3, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.setMemoryButton,   4, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.addToMemoryButton, 5, 0)

        for i in range(1, Calculator.NumDigitButtons):
            row    = ((9 - i) / 3) + 2
            column = ((i - 1) % 3) + 1
            mainLayout.addWidget(self.digitButtons[i], row, column)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.digitButtons[0],  5, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.pointButton,      5, 2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.changeSignButton, 5, 3)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.divisionButton, 2, 4)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.timesButton,    3, 4)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.minusButton,    4, 4)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.plusButton,     5, 4)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.squareRootButton, 2, 5)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.powerButton,      3, 5)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.reciprocalButton, 4, 5)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.equalButton,      5, 5)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Calculator")

    def digitClicked(self):
        clickedButton = self.sender()
        digitValue    = int(clickedButton.text())

        if self.display.text() == '0' and digitValue == 0.0:
            return

        if self.waitingForOperand:
            self.display.clear()
            self.waitingForOperand = False

        self.display.setText(self.display.text() + str(digitValue))

    def unaryOperatorClicked(self):
        clickedButton   = self.sender()
        clickedOperator = clickedButton.text()
        operand         = float(self.display.text())

        if clickedOperator == "Sqrt":
            if operand < 0.0:
                self.abortOperation()
                return

            result = math.sqrt(operand)
        elif clickedOperator == u"x\N{SUPERSCRIPT TWO}":
            result = math.pow(operand, 2.0)
        elif clickedOperator == "1/x":
            if operand == 0.0:
                self.abortOperation()
                return

            result = 1.0 / operand

        self.display.setText(str(result))
        self.waitingForOperand = True

    def additiveOperatorClicked(self):
        clickedButton   = self.sender()
        clickedOperator = clickedButton.text()
        operand         = float(self.display.text())

        if self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator:
            if not self.calculate(operand, self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator):
                self.abortOperation()
                return

            self.display.setText(str(self.factorSoFar))
            operand          = self.factorSoFar
            self.factorSoFar = 0.0
            self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator = ''

        if self.pendingAdditiveOperator:
            if not self.calculate(operand, self.pendingAdditiveOperator):
                self.abortOperation()
                return

            self.display.setText(str(self.sumSoFar))
        else:
            self.sumSoFar = operand

        self.pendingAdditiveOperator = clickedOperator
        self.waitingForOperand       = True

    def multiplicativeOperatorClicked(self):
        clickedButton   = self.sender()
        clickedOperator = clickedButton.text()
        operand         = float(self.display.text())

        if self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator:
            if not self.calculate(operand, self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator):
                self.abortOperation()
                return

            self.display.setText(str(self.factorSoFar))
        else:
            self.factorSoFar = operand

        self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator = clickedOperator
        self.waitingForOperand = True

    def equalClicked(self):
        operand = float(self.display.text())

        if self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator:
            if not self.calculate(operand, self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator):
                self.abortOperation()
                return

            operand          = self.factorSoFar
            self.factorSoFar = 0.0
            self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator = ''

        if self.pendingAdditiveOperator:
            if not self.calculate(operand, self.pendingAdditiveOperator):
                self.abortOperation()
                return

            self.pendingAdditiveOperator = ''
        else:
            self.sumSoFar = operand

        self.display.setText(str(self.sumSoFar))
        self.sumSoFar = 0.0
        self.waitingForOperand = True

    def pointClicked(self):
        if self.waitingForOperand:
            self.display.setText('0')

        if "." not in self.display.text():
            self.display.setText(self.display.text() + ".")

        self.waitingForOperand = False

    def changeSignClicked(self):
        text  = self.display.text()
        value = float(text)

        if value > 0.0:
            text = "-" + text
        elif value < 0.0:
            text = text[1:]

        self.display.setText(text)

    def backspaceClicked(self):
        if self.waitingForOperand:
            return

        text = self.display.text()[:-1]
        if not text:
            text = '0'
            self.waitingForOperand = True

        self.display.setText(text)

    def clear(self):
        if self.waitingForOperand:
            return

        self.display.setText('0')
        self.waitingForOperand = True

    def clearAll(self):
        self.sumSoFar    = 0.0
        self.factorSoFar = 0.0
        self.pendingAdditiveOperator       = ''
        self.pendingMultiplicativeOperator = ''
        self.display.setText('0')
        self.waitingForOperand = True

    def clearMemory(self):
        self.sumInMemory = 0.0

    def readMemory(self):
        self.display.setText(str(self.sumInMemory))
        self.waitingForOperand = True

    def setMemory(self):
        self.equalClicked()
        self.sumInMemory = float(self.display.text())

    def addToMemory(self):
        self.equalClicked()
        self.sumInMemory += float(self.display.text())

    def createButton(self, text, member):
        button = Button(text)
        button.clicked.connect(member)
        return button

    def abortOperation(self):
        self.clearAll()
        self.display.setText("####")

    def calculate(self, rightOperand, pendingOperator):
        if pendingOperator == "+":
            self.sumSoFar += rightOperand
        elif pendingOperator == "-":
            self.sumSoFar -= rightOperand
        elif pendingOperator == u"\N{MULTIPLICATION SIGN}":
            self.factorSoFar *= rightOperand
        elif pendingOperator == u"\N{DIVISION SIGN}":
            if rightOperand == 0.0:
                return False

            self.factorSoFar /= rightOperand

        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app  = QApplication(sys.argv)
    calc = Calculator()
    calc.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Дерзайте, и у вас все получится!